# No entries in pg_hba.conf

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc, debian

Ok first of all i'm french so sorry for the possible incomprehension or bad translate of error messages.

I have a Raspberry, with a Tomcat server on. Also, i use Postgresql too.

On my website, The server side connect to the localhost to access to the database with the JDBC plugin, all works great.

But now i'm trying to developp a Java Program, which one need to connect to the sql database.

But the program have as target to being deployed. So, I can't use "localhost" to connect to the database. On my computer, i'm trying to connect to my Raspberry's database with the JDBC and the few following code :

```
<code>

    public class DB {
        Connection co;
        PreparedStatement ps;

        public DB() {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.47:5432/database?sslmode=require", "username", "password");
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {System.out.println(e);}
            catch (SQLException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        }
    }

</code>
```

But when i try to connect, i get the following error :

" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: aucune entr?e dans pg_hba.conf pour l'h?te << 192.168.1.73 >>, utilisateur << username >>,
base de donn?es << database >>, SSL actif "

Which means "No entries in pg_hba.conf for the host..." but i tried to add entries in pg_hba.conf, like this :

host all postgres 192.168.0.0/24 trust

host databaseName userName 192.168.0.0/24 md5

host all all 0.0.0.0/24 md5

but this didn't worked (maybe bad row ? how can i just authorize the user "username" with a password ?)

I added the listen_addresses='*' in postgres.conf too.

Someone know how i need to configure all ?

My computer is on the same WIFI than my Raspberry. Does i need to connect with an external computer on an external WIFI ?

Maybe i did another mistake ?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved it by myself, i added these line to pg_hba.conf :

host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

now i have to work on the security. Thanks by the way.